Delphi 11 .NET assembly list import wizard is empty
When I tried to open the delphi 11 IDE wizard on importing .NET component the list is empty :
Empty List 1
Empty List 2
To me it seems impossible that the system has no .NET assemblies registered.
If I try top load the DLL by myself, with the "add" button, I got this message ->
Empty List 3
what could cause this, and how to solve this ?

Have you visited the first google result for your error code, which is https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2055-import-net-assembly-list-is-empty/?

Yes I did, but does not seem to bring an answer. So i'm trying here.

"It's a bug that's still not fixed" is an answer though, isn't it? Just not the one you want.

May there is a simple workaround to this "bug"?

I'm sure you already read the "if i have fewer than around 7 property/functions the import goes well" part.

This thread on delphipraxis cannot be the sole info on this topic...
I wonder if the issue is not related to .NET bound to the old framework .Net SDK and the move to ".Net Core" ?
